# Hibernate JPA SqlResultSetMapping nesting class constructors

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am new to Hibernate and Spring programming, and I am trying to better understand annotations, and using it. My question is, can you nest ConstructorResults. My Current mapping would be similar to this.

```java
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="obj", 
    classes={
        ConstrutorResult(targetClass=ClassA.class, columns{
            @ColumnResult(name="type1key", type=String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name="type1desc", type=String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name="type2key", type=String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name="type2desc", type=String.class),
            ...
        }
    }
)
```

I am wondering if you can map to nested class's. So my class I am mapping to contains classes that handle their data separately, and are labeled as @Transient. So is something like the below possible?

```java
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="obj",
    classes={
        @ConstrutorResult(targetClass=ClassA.class, columns{
            @ConstrutorResult(targetClass=PropertyClassA.class, columns{
                @ColumnResult(name="type1key", type=String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="type1desc", type=String.class)
            },
            @ConstrutorResult(targetClass=PropertyClassA.class, columns{
                @ColumnResult(name="type2key", type=String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name="type2desc", type=String.class)
            }
            ...
        }
    }
)
```

I know this isn't valid code, I just wanted to know if there is a similar way of doing it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You would have to construct nested objects yourself in the constructor.

I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage). Since Blaze-Persistence supports advanced SQL concepts in the realm of the JPA model, you usually don't need to write native queries and can make use of Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views to do your result mapping.

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(EntityClassA.class)
public interface ClassA {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    EntityPropertyClassA getProperty1();
    EntityPropertyClassA getProperty2();

    @EntityView(EntityPropertyClassA.class)
    interface PropertyClassA {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`EntityClassA a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, EntityClassA.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

Comment: Its a shame its not supported. Would definitely try using your library, however, cant use any external libraries that are not supported by the rest of the project. I will definitely try out your library for some other projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are compacting the problem, @ConstructorResult will contains those values in sequence that is the output of query. I don't understand why you have mentioned two @ConstrutorResult in the above code snippet. Kindly elaborate the issue properly.

Comment: Im looking to call the constructer of PropertyClassA and constructer of PropertyClassB inside of the constructer for ClassA in the resultSetMapping annotation using the column values returned by the query. I am definitely trying to make the problem more compact. Sure I can call the constructor for those two classes inside ClassA's constructor thats called by the annotation. I would like to know if it is possible to create a more compact resultSetMap.